# Is there any free GUI for administering AD LDS (ADAM)?

Tags: user-interface, active-directory, administration, adam

I am researching if ADLDS or ADAM is suitable for handling the users of a company product. Currently we are using AD, but we are planning to scale to more customers without needing to buy CALs.

I got how to use ADSI Edit to add User & Groups, but I couldnt find any tool to do that like "Active Directory users and computers", and I would like to avoid developing one. Is there any free GUI to manage AD LDS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use an LDAP browser. [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/), which is working on the top of java (on both Windows and Linux) is the best Open source one.